# "With lines" in JavaPlot?

Tags: java, gnuplot, javaplot

I am using [JavaPlot](http://gnujavaplot.sourceforge.net/JavaPlot/About.html). In gnuplot, I would type

```
plot "data" with lines
```

In JavaPlot, I have

```
JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot();
p.addPlot(data);
p.plot();
```

Any idea how to get the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package namepackage;

import com.panayotis.gnuplot.JavaPlot;
import com.panayotis.gnuplot.plot.DataSetPlot;
import com.panayotis.gnuplot.style.PlotStyle;
import com.panayotis.gnuplot.style.Style;

/**
 * on NetBeans add library -> jar -> 
 * package namepackage;
 *
 * import com.panayotis.gnuplot.JavaPlot;
 * import com.panayotis.gnuplot.plot.DataSetPlot;
 * import com.panayotis.gnuplot.style.PlotStyle;
 * import com.panayotis.gnuplot.style.Style;
 * @author mkwest
 *
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot();
        double tab[][];

        tab = new double[2][2];
        tab[0][0] = 0.0000;
        tab[0][1] = 2.0000;
        tab[1][0] = 1.0000;
        tab[1][1] = 6.0000;
        PlotStyle myPlotStyle = new PlotStyle();
        myPlotStyle.setStyle(Style.LINES);
        DataSetPlot s = new DataSetPlot(tab);
        myPlotStyle.setLineWidth(1);
        DataSetPlot testDataSetPlot = new DataSetPlot(tab);
        //DataSetPlot.setPlotStyle(myPlotStyle);
        s.setPlotStyle(myPlotStyle);
        //p.newGraph();
        p.addPlot(s);
        p.newGraph();
        p.plot();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See my code below for example.

If you want use array:

```
    JavaPlot testPlot = new JavaPlot()

//Создаем стиль графика (create graph style)
PlotStyle myPlotStyle = new PlotStyle();
//Устанавливаем стиль
myPlotStyle.setStyle(Style.LINES);
//Устанавливаем ширину линий
myPlotStyle.setLineWidth(2);


 double[][] myArray = new double[100][2];
 for (j=0;j<100;j++)
 { myArray[j][0] = j+1;     //Значения x (x mean)
   myArray[j][1] = sin(j);  //Значения y (y mean)
 }
 //Создаем набор данных для графика на основе массива
 //(Create dataset for graph on the basis of array)
 DataSetPlot testDataSetPlot = new DataSetPlot(myArray);
 //Установим стиль графика (set graph style)
 dollarExDataSetPlot.setPlotStyle(myPlotStyle);
 //Установим название графика (set graph title)
 dollarExDataSetPlot.setTitle("Title test");

 testPlot.addPlot(testDataSetPlot);
 //Заголовок (plot title)
 dollarExchangePlot.setTitle("test");
 try
 { dollarExchangePlot.plot();}
 catch (Exception ex)
 {System.out.println(ex.toString());}
```

If you want use external file:

```
JavaPlot testPlot = new JavaPlot()

//Создаем стиль графика ========================================================
PlotStyle myPlotStyle = new PlotStyle();
//Устанавливаем стиль
myPlotStyle.setStyle(Style.LINES);
//Устанавливаем ширину линий
myPlotStyle.setLineWidth(2);

 //Создаем набор данных на основе файла для графика ============================ 
 File testFile = new File("test.txt");
 FileDataSet testFileDataSet;
 DataSetPlot testDataSetPlot;

    try {
        testFileDataSet = new FileDataSet(testFile);
        testDataSetPlot = new DataSetPlot(testFileDataSet);

        //Установим стиль графика
        testDataSetPlot.setPlotStyle(myPlotStyle);
        //Установим название графика
        testDataSetPlot.setTitle("test");

        testPlot.addPlot(testDataSetPlot);
        testPlot.setTitle("Title test");
        testPlot.plot();
        }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {System.out.println(ex.toString());}
```